# Find total price for an order using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a JPA application, with an entity diagram, that shows the relations between orders and customers.

I have an ItemType entity class as such:

```
@Entity
public class ItemType implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private int price;
List<OrderLine> orderlines;
```

the class contains a list of OrderLines because it has a one to many relationships to the orderline entity.

Here is my OrderLine entity. It contains a single instance of the ItemType class, because of the relationship.

```
@Entity
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private int quantity;
private Order order;
private ItemType itemtype;
```

I have a facade class, where i have made different methods, to calculate and select elements from my database, but i want to make a calculatePrice method, which multiplies the quantity from the orderline with the price from ItemType.

I know that the functions need to take both an ItemType instance and an OrderLine instance like such:

```
 public int getTotalPrice(ItemType itemtype, OrderLine orderline){


}
```

but I'm not sure if I should use NamedQueries within the entity classes, to get the data from the database, or I should use something like a value annotation, that can make a calculation.

Comment: I don't think this is primary opinion based question. Having a Query , or using Hibernate session have direct consequences and have different type of advantages based on the context. I vote against closing it for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, i was not sure, if you could do both, or what would be better code practise.

Comment: there is no better practice here. In 99% of the cases it is better to choose the cleanest, and most readable option. Sometimes when you work with application that relayes heavily on its Cache using Hibernate Session is more efficient because you will get more hits on the Cache compared to when you use a Query. When you use a query you transfer the load on the database. Which is not nessesarily a bad thing!

Comment: If I use a framework like EclipseLink, will it still work if I import the hibernate dependency and make the Formula annotation?

Comment: I dont think it is worth it the whole effort really.  It might be worth it only if you have desire to learn more hibernate :) As I said there is no bad option here in the general case.

Comment: I don't need to save the value in a field, so maybe it's possible to use the PreUpdate, and PrePersist annotations?

Comment: No you can not do that. You want to be able to read the property. If you go for the Java version you don't need to maintain a property at all. Just do one method inside the OrderLine calculateTotalPrice, get the value from ItemType with "this" perform the calculation and return the result. Job done.

Comment: You don't need to pass arguments at all to this method if it is positioned in your OrderLine

Comment: Yes but the thing, is that the price in ItemType and quantity is in OrderLine, so I need the value from both Entities/tables

Comment: You need to map ItemType with OneToOne and ensure it is initialized. Set FetchType.Eager to ensure it is initialized.

Comment: Sory I mean ManyToOne

Comment: Is it the entire object or just the one variable?

Comment: Inside OrderLine above the itemType https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0.2/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html and don't forget the joincolumn. You need it in order to tell eclipslink how to perform the join

Comment: but OrderLine and ItemType or two different classes/Entities?

Comment: Oh i get it now.. Should it cascade aswell?

Comment: That is a whole different question :) Do more reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are valid and have pluses and minuses.

If you define it as Query, what you will gain is less java code. The query will be bound to your entity , in a way it would be less verbose.

On the cons side you will not be able to take advantage of the Level 1 cache that hibernate session presents. The only way to cache the results would be through second level query cache if you configure it and still this type of caching is not very good.

If you decide to go with java you will take full advantage of your Hibernate Session and its functionality. You will have very good control over what queries how often how much are executed. You will be able to debug your Java code. You will be able to unit test it.

Summary of your options:

1. Use a Query, call it from your service.
2. Use a Formula so that you don't need to invoke your Query, but instead once you load the entity your formula will get evaluated.
3. Do a java method that is traversing your tree and calculating the value. In a Cache intensive application this is the most performant way to go, also it is very easy to Unit test.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. So if I want to go with java, I could make a value annotation over the primary data type, to make the calculation , and use it inside my method?